# Logging users out with basic authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I've searched around and there doesn't seem to be a non-hacky way to clear the user credentials from the browser using basic authentication.

I'm building a WebAPI with an HTML client that accepts username/password - if the user logs in, they should certainly be able to log out as well, or the system should automatically log out after a certain time period.

Is there any standard way to accomplish this with Basic Auth (over SSL), or should I start looking into other forms of authentication?

Edit: looking into the SimpleMembershipProvider, would there be anything "wrong" with extending the Membership table with an "IsLoggedIn" property that I can toggle and check with every request?  If they click logout, then I redirect to the login page and return 401 Unauthorized unless they submit their credentials again.  Does this sound ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Until the time the browser is closed, credentials are cached by the browser. There is no non-hacky way to clear the credentials. Check this [out](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/25/using-the-browsers-native-login-prompt/).

Comment: Got it.  It seems like Basic authentication is not a good solution then, for securing a WebAPI that has HTTP/JS clients.  Would you agree?

Comment: Yes, there are constraints. Personally, I'll avoid Basic authn with browser clients, not just because of the lack of a way to log out but also because of the potential XSRF issues. But I'll not say basic authentication is just plain bad. It has a few characteristics one need to be aware of and work accordingly.

Comment: You coud try redirecting with 302 status code and provide invalid user credential in redirected url.